# An error when I use file_get_contents, return null

Tags: php

I made a php file for find and return an Instagram post likes count. I uploaded this php file on **api.mydomain.com**. This is the codes:

```
<?php
$url = $_GET["url"];//Instagram Post Link
$resp = file_get_contents("$url?__a=1");
$r = json_decode($resp,true);
if (strpos($resp, 'edge_media_preview_like') !== false) {
    $start_counter = $r['graphql']['shortcode_media']['edge_media_preview_like']['count'];
}else{
    $start_counter="ERROR";
}
return $start_counter;
```

When I send request with my browser myself, it return the likes count.
But when I send request to **api.mydomain.com** with the following codes that uploaded on my host, I receive null.

```
<?php
$InstagramPost = "https://www.instagram.com/p/CETxYxtFq8h/"; //an Instagram post for example
$API_LINK = "http://api.mydomain.com?url=$InstagramPost";
$resp = file_get_contents($API_LINK);
echo $resp;
```

Why does this problem arise?

Comment: Your host may have a firewall blocking it, or they may not have `fopen_url` enabled. Enable warnings and see the warning from `file_get_contents()` is.

Comment: you may be better using [`cURL`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should always validate input variable. In your case you should validate `$_GET["url"]` because anyone could use your **api.mydomain.com** for bad things, f.e. DoS.

Next thing is that you should escape an url before inserting it inside the other url:

```
$InstagramPost = "https://www.instagram.com/p/CETxYxtFq8h/";
$instaEscaped = rawurlencode($InstagramPost);
$API_LINK = "http://api.mydomain.com?url=$instaEscaped";
```

And last this is that before doing `json_decode` you'd better check given response. Maybe it's already `false`:

```
$url = $_GET["url"];
$resp = file_get_contents("$url?__a=1");
if (false === $resp) {
  // do something
}

$r = json_decode($resp,true);
```